# SQL Pivot: Can I make the pivot list dynamic without using stored proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Here is my SQL containing a pivot:

```
select * from (
    select 
        [event_id]
        ,[attnum]
        ,PollId
        ,PollResponseDisplayText
    from 
        [dbo].[v_PollReportDetails2]
) as tmp
pivot (max(tmp.[PollResponseDisplayText])
for tmp.PollId in ([703],[805],[806],[807],[808],[809])) as pivot_table
```

I want to change the pivot list to be something like this:

```
for tmp.PollId in (select PollId 
                    from Polls 
                    where event_id = 100100
                    and isVisible = 1)) as pivot_table
```

I can do this all in a stored proc and dynamically generate a SQL statement to feed into an `execute()` statement, but I need to be able to do this in a view.

Comment: could you please add some sample data of your tables

Comment: You cannot - views can have only static definitions (at least in SQL server - you didn't tag your DBMS).

Comment: PIVOT clause requires these distinct values to be known at query design time (before query execution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places, but I can't seem to find official documentation that actually says that this can't be done.  But after hours of experimenting and discussions, Apparently, this can not be done this way.

@aeoluseros said it best in his comment,

> syntax of PIVOT clause requires these distinct values to be known at
> query design time. So you cannot use that in view

Logically, this would make sense, because as we add rows to the table over time, it would have the potential to add columns dynamically to the view result.

Thanks  @Damien_The_Unbeliever for additional clarification, see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax

Comment: You're not going to find documentation on everything that *isn't* possible with any given feature. However, if you look at the [syntax diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) (and learn a bit about SQL Server's syntax diagrams) you'll realised that it specifically requires a fixed set of columns. There's no alternatives presented to `IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])`